# Cannot call the mysql stored procedures in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

im trying to call two stored proceedures one after the other using php and PDO.. but when i try to do that it returns an error saying

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:
 General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are
 active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is
 only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting 
 the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.'
```

As you'll could see im alreay using the `MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`attribute too, but still i get the error.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbConfig->host;dbname=".$dbConfig->name, $dbConfig->username, $dbConfig->password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);

    $tables = array();
    $table_count = $conn->prepare("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'milepostdb' AND table_name LIKE 'table_%' ");
    $table_count->execute();

    while ($data = $table_count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $table = $data["TABLE_NAME"];

        //$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM   $table WHERE time > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 WEEK)");//this works perfectly
        $result = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_project_time_interval('$table')");

        $result->execute();// place where the error triggers

        $count = $result->rowCount();
        if($count>0){
            $exc = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_weekly_project_report('$table')");
            $exc->execute();
            while($finalRes = $exc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                        $tables[] = $finalRes;
             }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Instead of keeping the resultset open and iterating over it and doing a subquery while iterating over it, do `fetchAll` to put all the resultset in an array, then iterate over the array, that way you can close the resultset before doing the subquery.

Comment: i understand what you said... but in order to implement it technically can you please give me a small guide to the code

Comment: anybody who konws pdo

Comment: Do your Sprocs return result sets or just basic values? How many of each?

Answer (score 1):

Your resultset is still open from the first SELECT statement. You'll need to close the cursor before running more queries. Note that doing a fetchAll() will close the cursor for you automatically.

```
$table_count = $conn->prepare("SELECT .......");
$table_count->execute();
$resultset = $table_count->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($resultset as $data) {
    $result = $conn->prepare("CALL .......");
    $result->execute(); 
    $resultset2 = $table_count->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```